# biblatex-chicago and \autocite tag modification

Tags: biblatex-chicago

All,

Some examples are given below and please suggest how can I handle the tag `\autocite` as like as `natbib` options, e.g., `\citep`, `\citet`, `\citealp`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{NationalSecurityAgency_2012,
  title = {{{SKYNET}}: {{Courier Detection}} via {{Machine Learning}}},
  url = {https://theintercept.com/document/2015/05/08/skynet-courier/},
  shorttitle = {{{SKYNET}}},
  timestamp = {2015-10-29T10:36:06Z},
  journaltitle = {The Intercept},
  author = {National Security Agency},
  urldate = {2015-10-29},
  date = {2012}
}
@book{smith2,
  author = {Smith, John},
  title = {Second Book},
  date = {2013-11-02}
}
\end{filecontents}
%
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,doi=false,url=false,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\AtEveryBibitem{% Clean up the bibtex rather than editing it
    \ifentrytype{online}
        {}
        {\clearfield{urlyear}\clearfield{urlmonth}\clearfield{urlday}}}%
\begin{document}
Foo \autocite{smith2}.

(see the U.S. government's \texttt{SkyNet} for one
example of a machine learning surveillance system
\autocite{NationalSecurityAgency_2012})
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

In the above example, I do not need the ( and ) for the tag `\autocite{NationalSecurityAgency_2012}` also some times need the tag only for the year also.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 2):

`\autocite` is not a panacea. It can't be very smart. All it does is choose a type of citation that is, on average, appropriate given the style. There are still other citation commands available. In your case the one you want is `\textcite`, which produces a citation suitable for use in running text. But there is a full range tht corresponds to the natbib commands you mention.

The various different commands are dealt with at 3.8.1 and 3.8.2 of the Manual, or in chapter 5 of my [shorter guide](https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial/releases). Of course individual styles will alter them, and in some cases they are redundant, but it is worth knowing the full range, and perfectly appropriate to use that range and not just `\autocite`.